# Query to map a particular database to a syslogin

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to map a database to a syslogin.

Following is the query I have used to create login and make it a db_owner but after the execution, I can see a tick as db_owner for that database in UserMapping tab ,but there's no tick on the database itself that means it's not mapped with the database

```
CREATE LOGIN [TRAINW7X64CA04\Test8] from Windows with default_database = Eclipse;
Use Eclipse
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'TRAINW7X64CA04\Test8'
```

Can some help me with the mapping of the database as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a [`CREATE USER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx) to add them in as a database principal.

```
CREATE LOGIN [TRAINW7X64CA04\Test8] from Windows with default_database = Eclipse;
Use Eclipse;
CREATE USER [TRAINW7X64CA04\Test8];
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'TRAINW7X64CA04\Test8';
```

Comment: Thanks, I was under the impression why to create a user when you are already creating login user.But, this worked perfectly fine for me.